# Execution of Fallback function with more 2300 gas

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-limit, fallback-function

I have tested a contract having a fallback function which updated a state variable (cost 5000 gas). I sent an amount of Ether to this contract with 100000 gas limit. The transaction is valid. As explained in [solidity considerations](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html), it should be fail because gas stipend is 2300. Can someone help me explain?

Comment: I misunderstood explanation in document. If send ETH from an external account to a contract, gas is computed based on how many gases the fallback function return. On the other hand, sending ETH from a contract to another contract will be limited in gas stipend.

Answer (score 17):

I was confused by this questions and self answer, so I will try to clarify.

The OP sent 1,000,000 gas to a smart contract from an external account. He/she incorrectly read the Solidity documentation to say that there was a 'stipend' of only 2300 gas on such a transaction, but that was mistaken.

The 'stipend' applies to internal `sends` from one smart contract to another. Because `send` has no way to specify the gas amount, (whereas `call` does), Solidity imposes a maximum amount of gas (i.e. 2300).

Because the OP's transaction was not an internal contract-to-contract `send` the 2300 stipend did not apply and the transaction went through.