# How transaction with gas used ok 28k succeed for payable?

Tags: solidity, gas-limit, payable

I'm trying to understand what I can do in fallback payable (I have read the docs and I know what I can't do for sure).

Here is my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract SmartMsgData {
    // events
    event onDeposit(int128 id, address person, uint amount);

    function bytesToBytes16(bytes b, uint offset) private pure returns (bytes16) {
      bytes16 out;

      for (uint i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        out |= bytes16(b[offset + i] & 0xFF) >> (i * 8);
      }
      return out;
    }

    function () payable external {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        require(msg.data.length == 16); // 16 bytes = int128

        // TODO: add checking for msg.value if i have enough gas

        int128 id = int128(bytesToBytes16(msg.data, 0));
        address person = msg.sender;
        uint amount = msg.value;

        // fire event
        emit onDeposit(id, person, amount);
    }
}
```

I've sent some amount from one address to contract address with data provided on myetherwallet.com with metamask.

Here is succeeded [transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x77dfb7b62a721e094a765c84059584b80794e1222640192c6b7116a7f2f85379). You can see gas used is **27826**.
However, in the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html) it's written that fallback payable function can rely on **2300** of gas only:

> In the worst case, the fallback function can only rely on 2300 gas being available

How did the transaction succeed if gas used exceeds the limit? Will it work in 100% of cases or depends on anything (miner, etc)?

Ideally, I'd check `msg.value` to be valid (within some range) so I'm trying to figure out if I have enough gas to read struct from storage and check it. How can I measure gas requirement beforehand as Remix evaluates loops incorrectly and measures gas requirement for `bytesToBytes16(..)` as `infinite`?

Answer (score 2):

The limit of 2300 only applies for contract-to-contract transactions. Otherwise there is no such strict limit. So all address-to-contract transactions to the fallback function with enough gas limit should succeed.

You can read a bit more details and explanation at [Execution of Fallback function with more 2300 gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11237/execution-of-fallback-function-with-more-2300-gas) .

Answer (score 0):

Your payable function execution some other operation then it should consume more gas.

If gas used exceed the gas limit the tnx will be error.

Comment: so you can confirm 2300 gas limit is just to contract-to-contract call and the is no *special* limitation to just sending eth to contract?

Comment: I think so because we cannot set gas limit when do contract-to-contract call; otherwise, we can set gas limit for our tnx.

People usually to set gas limit high then they send eth to a contract to buy token of an ICO then I think there's no special limitation to just sending eth to contract

Comment: You can set the gas limit when making a contract to contract call

Comment: ah okay, so 2300 just is the default one?

Comment: @RaghavSood How to set gas limit when making a contract to contract call?