# Persistent out of gas error with truffle latest on receive (Fallback) function

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, crowdsale, binance

I am having a persistent issue programming receive fallback function on an smart contract where I am programming an staged pre-sale of a Token. When I try on Remix transaction looks as done, but it doesn't update the state as needed, and in truffle, I can't get any transaction ID to debug as it always fails.

https://github.com/artfortressonlinenft/master_solidityv2/blob/master/contracts/Ancestry.sol

On line 437 is the funcion buyTokens called by receive, and buyTokens call preValidatePurchase where I think is the fault. I am not sure.

I am a very begineer solidity developer already learning... and I'll be grateful if could you provide some advice. Thanks in advance.

```
/**
     * @dev Extend parent behavior requiring purchase to respect investor min/max funding cap.
     * @param _beneficiary Token purchaser
     * @param _weiAmount Amount of wei contributed
     */
    function _preValidatePurchase(address _beneficiary, uint256 _weiAmount)
        internal
    {
        uint256 _existingContribution;
        uint256 _newContribution;

        require(
            _beneficiary != address(0),
            "Address 0x000...000 can't purchase"
        );

        if (stage == CrowdsaleStage.PreICO1) {
            require(
                investorTrack[_beneficiary].isWhtlP1 == true,
                "Sorry your address has not been whitelisted to enter Private Sale 1"
            );

            _existingContribution = investorTrack[_beneficiary].contributionP1;
            _newContribution = _existingContribution.add(_weiAmount);
            require(
                _newContribution >= investorMinCap &&
                    _newContribution <= investorMaxCap,
                "You can contribute from 0.2 to 1 BNB, no more as total"
            );
            investorTrack[_beneficiary].contributionP1 = _newContribution;
        } else if (stage == CrowdsaleStage.PreICO2) {
            require(
                investorTrack[_beneficiary].isWhtlP2 == true,
                "Sorry your address has not been whitelisted to enter Private Sale 2"
            );

            _existingContribution = investorTrack[_beneficiary].contributionP2;
            _newContribution = _existingContribution.add(_existingContribution);
            _newContribution = _newContribution.add(_weiAmount);
            require(
                _newContribution >= investorMinCap &&
                    _newContribution <= investorMaxCap,
                "You can contribute from 0.2 to 1 BNB, no more as total on both presales"
            );
            investorTrack[_beneficiary].contributionP2 = _newContribution;
        } else revert("Private Sales phases are both ended");
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debuggin in Remix? I'll suggest to comment and uncomment code until you arrive to the line that causes the revert.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have seen that receive function has a fix low gas quantity to spent and the solution was on turning mere receive function into an external payable one...

Comment: Great! The famous gas stipend limit of 2300. It will be nice if you add that as the answer so the question can be marked as resolved.

Comment: Of course! could you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: There's a text area below the question where you can write how did you solve the problem. You will find more details about the gas stipend in this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/77521/internal-contract-to-contract-call.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that receive function has a fix low gas quantity to spent and the solution was on turning mere receive function into an external payable one...